# Firebase functions - Could not find parent property in onWrite() trigger

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

In Firebase functions documentation it mentions that this

```
event.data.ref.parent
```

in

> Before (<= v0.9.1)

has been changed to

```
snap.ref.parent
```

in

> Now (>= v1.0.0)

But that returns an undefined in `onWrite(snap, context)` trigger. What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onWrite` has the [`change`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change) (ex: `onWrite((change,context)`) parameter which contains the `before` and  `after` fields. Each of these is a `DataSnapshot` with methods available in [`admin.database.DataSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.database.DataSnapshot). So in your case you need to use:

```
change.after.ref.parent
```

Check this:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff#realtime-database

Comment: The OP is apparently answering about the "adminRef replaced by ref" part of the documentation.

Comment: if he uses `onCreate` then `snap.ref.parent` will work as explained in the "adminRef replaced by ref". But he is using `onWrite`.

Comment: @PeterHaddad that worked! One more question though, how do I get value of other child of parent? For example other node's name is 'token'

Comment: You need to click on the link to check how in details, butif you want the node `token` then do `const datas=change.after.val(); const tokens=datas.token` @minimalist

Comment: @PeterHaddad this is returning undefined. token is not child of current ref but sibling. For which i need get to parent and then token.

Comment: @minimalist you need to write another question, since it is not related to this with the code that you are using, what you are trying to get, and screenshot of the database

Comment: @PeterHaddad Okay. I'll send you a link.

Comment: @PeterHaddad check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52220760/firebase-functions-get-sibling-of-current-datasnapshot