# Firebase functions - get sibling of current DataSnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My database is structured as follows
[image]

I am listening to actives node by using `onWrite(snapshot, context)` in firebase cloud functions. I want to get the value of token node based on change in actives.

My trigger function is as follows.

```
exports.sendNotification = functions.database.ref('root/users/{userid}/actives/{pushId}')
.onWrite((event, context) => {

var token; 

var active_userid = context.params.pushId;
   if(event.after._data != null){ 
        console.log(event.after.ref.parent.parent);

   }else{

       console.log('data is null')

   } 
return 0;

});
```

How do I get token node and read its value?

Comment: can you log `active_userid` and tell me what you get in the console? after `var active_userid = context.params.pushId;` write `console.log(active_userid)`

Comment: @PeterHaddad using the image about I m getting hasnain

Comment: Make your pushId is not null or ""(empty).

Comment: @MayurPatel it's not pushId. check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it by

```
 var ref = event.after.ref.parent.parent.child('token');

          ref.on('value', function(snapshot) {
                        console.log(`token value : ${snapshot.val()}`);
                        });
```

Comment: FYI, within a Cloud Function it is better to use `once()` instead of `on()`

Comment: @RenaudTarnec how?

Comment: `var ref = event.after.ref.parent.parent.child('token'); return ref.once('value').then(function(snapshot) {});` see https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.database.Reference#once

Comment: Got it. Thank you @RenaudTarnec